# How can I read the lines of a file into an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a file named *test.txt* that is like this:

> Test
>   Foo
>   Bar

But I want to put each line in a array and print the lines like this:

> line1 line2 line3

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
open(my $fh, "<", "test.txt")
    or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
while(<$fh>) { 
    chomp; 
    push @array, $_;
} 
close $fh;

print join " ", @array;
```

Comment: +1 for strictures, lexical filehandles and the 3-arg `open`. :)

Comment: You should check if file was opened successfully. Always. Or `use autodie;`

Answer (score 17):

Here is my single liner:

```
perl -e 'chomp(@a = <>); print join(" ", @a)' test.txt
```

Explanation:

- read file by lines into `@a` array
- `chomp(..)` - remove EOL symbols for each line
- concatenate `@a` using space as separator
- print result
- pass file name as parameter

Comment: `perl -le 'chomp(@a=<>); print "@a"' file ..`

Comment: Thank you. I've never seen that shorthand way of loading and chomping an array at the same time before.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic example looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(F, "<", "test.txt") or die("Cannot open test.txt: $!\n"); # (1)
my @lines = ();
while(<F>) { chomp; push(@lines, $_); } # (2)
close(F);

print "@lines"; # (3) stringify
```

(1) is the place where the file is opened.

(2) File handles work nicely within list enviroments (scalar/list environments are defined by the left value), so if you assign an array to a file handle, all the lines are slurped into the array. The lines are delimited (ended) by the value of `$/`, the input record separator. If you `use English;`, you can use `$IRS` or `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`. This value defaults to the newline character `\n`;

While this seemed to be a nice idea, I've just forgot the fact that if you print all the lines, the ending `\n` will be printed too. Baaad me.

Originally the code was:

```
my @lines = <F>;
```

instead of the `while` loop. This is still a viable alternative, but you should swap (3) with `chomp`ing and then printing/stringifying all the elements:

```
for (@lines) { chomp; }
print "@lines";
```

(3) Stringifying means converting an array to a string and inserting the value `$"` between the array elements. This defaults to a space.

See: [the perlvar page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

So the actual 2nd try is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(F, "<", "test.txt") or die("Cannot open test.txt: $!\n"); # (1)
my @lines = <F>; # (2)
close(F);
chomp(@lines);

print "@lines"; # (3) stringify
```

Comment: There is shortcut for chomp: `chomp(@lines);`

Answer (score 2):

One more answer for you to choose from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

open(FILE, "<", "test.txt") or die("Can't open file");
@lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
chomp(@lines);
print join(" ", @lines);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself slurping files frequently, you could use the [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp/lib/File/Slurp.pm)  module from CPAN:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my @lines = read_file('test.txt');
chomp @lines;
print "@lines\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest version I could come up with:

```
perl -l040 -pe';' < test.txt
```

---

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
perl -pe'
  chomp; $\ = $/; # -l
  $\ = 040;       # -040
'
```

and:

```
perl -e'
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
      chomp; $\ = $/; # -l
      $\ = " ";       # -040
    } continue {
      print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that do this (assume the below code inside script.pl) :

```
use strict;
use warnings
my @array = <> ;
chomp @array;
print "@array";
```

It is run by:

```
scirpt.pl [your file]
```